# Passing an object to views/layout.ejs in sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am having a hard time trying to pass an object to the layout of my project in order to get a list of categories i need to show in the navbar. I have been trying o couple of solutions here and all relates on using a policy and assigning res.locals.myVar = someObj, the problem is that res.locals and also using req.options.locals.myVar are only available in the controller action's view and not the layout

So far i got this.

// getRoomList POLICY

```
Room.find().exec(function(err, rooms) {
    if (err) {
        return res.badRequest('Something went wrong.');
    }
    if (rooms) {
        res.locals.roomlist = rooms;
        next();
    } else {
        res.notFound();
    }
});
```

// config/policies

```
'*': 'getRoomList'
```

// In layout.ejs

```
<%= roomlist %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its ok to use policy to save data into the `res.locals`, but in my implementation I save data to the request itself and send it to the view in the controller (It looks clearer to me)

**config/policies/getCategories**

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next){
  Categories.find().exec(function(err, models) {
      if (err) return res.badRequest("Error");
      req.categories = models;
      next();
  });
}
```

**api/controllers/ABCController.js**

```
module.exports = {
   index : function(req, res, next){
      res.view('page/index', {
          categories : req.categories
      });
    }
}
```

**config/policies.js**

```
ABCController : {
   index: ['getCategories', 'getProfiles']
   // add this policy to any page who needs nav bar categories
}
```

**config/routes.js

```
'/home/': {
  controller: "ABCController",
  action: "index"
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that i dont want any particular view to handle the nav bar categories. The "nav bar" is in the layout.

Comment: In that case, your solution is better I think, make every requests have the same policy to save the res.locals variables

Comment: Well the problem is that my solution wont work for this case.

Comment: really? it works for me. did you try print the ```res.locals``` in the controller? Maybe provide which version of Sails you're using would be helpful